# Merge and return an id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a procedure that when a row is found, that matches the inputed values, it returns that rows ID, and if a matching row is not found it inserts the values and outputs the inserted ID. The ID is a identity colume.

I've been trying to modify the following code (fake fields), but I dont think I can do what i want to in this code.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsertProc]
        @ID    varchar(20),
        @Input varchar(20)
    AS
        MERGE INTO table
    USING 
        (SELECT @Input AS 'Input', @ID AS 'ID') AS Query
        -- Search predicates
        --
        ON Query.ID = table.ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        -- Update part of the 'UPSERT'
        --  
        UPDATE SET
            table.Input=Query.Input
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        -- INSERT part of the 'UPSERT'
        --
        INSERT (Input) VALUES(Query.Input);
    RETURN 0
```

Is there a way to make this kind of precedure?

Comment: what exactly doesnt work?

Comment: `MERGE` supports the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  `OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @tableVariable`, then return that.

Comment: I solved a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207709/generating-diff-list-based-on-before-and-after-snapshots-of-database-transactio/29209882#29209882)

Comment: Be careful here using MERGE for an upsert. It can cause deadlocks and is apparently "by design". https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/723696/basic-merge-upsert-causing-deadlocks

Comment: @BaconBits I've been trying the output in all kinds of ways and even your example always return an error.  Is this the correct way to use the OUTPUT `INSERT (Input) OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @tableVariable VALUES(Query.Input);`

Comment: @Hauba did you declare the tablevariable first ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk is a variable like `@returnID int` enough or do i have to create a temporary table with a single columne.

Comment: @Hauba if you want to redirect your result, you will have to use a table variable. However you can't return a table variable from a stored procedure, so you can just output them like I did in my link earlier

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Bit more work but after implementing a solution based on your first link the procedure works very well and is returning correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your procedure:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

It will work with both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` parts of your `MERGE`.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - It is not possible for the Procedure provided to update more than 1 value.  It only accepts 1 ID as input, and author stated that ID is an identity column.

Comment: After some more testing this solution began to return wrong ID's, on the UPDATE part it began to return NULL or the last known inputed ID.